# aws cloudsearch uploadDocument returning signaturedoesnotmatch

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

Im using com.amazonaws.services.cloudsearchdomain.AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient to `uploadDocuments()` with passing AWS secretkey and access id, End points .
Access Policy - Access all for all services
It is returning

> Service: AmazonCloudSearchDomain; Status Code: 403; Error Code:
>   SignatureDoesNotMatch;

But with same package i have tried `search()` with same credentials , im getting search result correctly as expected. 
Some one please help for above exception

Comment: Post your code and read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by your access policy allowing public access to `search` requests, but not `upload`.  So there may be an issue with the credentials being passed, but you don't see that error when performing search requests, because credentials aren't necessary for that type of request.

For example, this access policy below would allow anyone to search without presenting credentials.  But any other operation (like uploading documents) would require a valid set of credentials that have access to the CloudSearch domain.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "cloudsearch:search"
    }
  ]
}
```